# Travis uses ant instead of maven

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I have a repo with 3 maven projects for which I want to use Travis.

As the `pom.xml` is not in the root of the repo, Travis doesn't see it and tries to build with `build.xml`, but it fails.

I tried setting custom build script, but Travis seems not to keep trying to build with `Ant`.

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: java
sudo: false

matrix:
 include:
  - os: linux
    jdk: oraclejdk8
script: ./build.sh
cache:
 directories:
  - $HOME/.m2
```

And build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ev
cd Code/Java/DBServer
mvn clean install
```

Location of pom.xml is `Code/Java/DBServer/pom.xml`

How to make Travis build with Maven?

Comment: Why is the pom.xml not in the root of the repo? If possible, put it there.

Comment: pom.xml is not in the root of the repo, because I have 3 maven projects in one repo. So my pom.xml files are in 3 different directories. And I really would not like to change that structure.

Comment: I don't know Travis, but in the build systems I know you build separate projects separately and give the directory of the pom to each build.

Comment: Yup, and this is what I was trying to do. I wanted to specify path to pom.xml also with Travis script:  mvn -q -B -f Code/Java/Bookstore/pom.xml clean verify, but it didn't work neither. This should tell Travis to build with maven and where is pom.xml, but it is still  executing ant test

Comment: You could use a parent pom, specifying the modules you want to build.

Comment: That's also smth that I was thinking about, but didn't know how to do it (I'm new to maven). However answer by StephenG solved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that travis is using a default Ant build for the `install` phase.

I'd try blanking out the `install` phase of travis with a `.travis.yml` like this:

```
language: java
sudo: false
os: linux
jdk: oraclejdk8
install: 
script: ./build.sh
cache:
 directories:
  - $HOME/.m2
```